# STTwitter: Choosing what Account to Use

Tags: objective-c, twitter, sttwitter

I'm using STTwitter to post a message to twitter using the API.

I have two active Twitter profile on my OSX Mavericks in the "Internet Accounts" under systems preferences. One is my personal account, the other is something I'm working on.

I'd like to post a tweet to account #2.

Using STTwitterAPI My code looks like this:

```
twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];
```

Now, the rest of the code worked but it's using the wrong account (it's not the *first account*).

I looked through the code and I thought I could use something like this:

```
twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithAccount:(ACAccount *)];
```

And get my account from the store. Now, is there a way to get an "ACAccount" by handle (I can't find it anywhere) or is there a way to have a pop-up show to select which account to use? STTwitter didn't show this.

I saw in the API code they are returning the 'index 0' of accounts so I thought about creating a new method

> twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithHandle:(NSString *)];

but not sure if it's the right way to go.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I made a bunch of changes to use an NSAlert for selection and saving the preferred account in NSDefault. Will leave this open in case someone knows a better way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the accounts defined in System Preferences like this:

```
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if(granted == NO) return;

    self.osxAccounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
}];
```

Yan can then let the user select the `ACAccount` instance she wants to use.

See [STTwitter OS X demo project](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_osx/STTwitterDemoOSX/STAuthenticationVC.m#L94) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you! This is more or less what I did. If osxAccounts was 1 use that one otherwise show an NSAlert with a selector. Did the trick!